# How to check the validity of the value of PlotStyle option for 2D graph?

Tags: plotting, options

For the 2D graphic function like `Plot, ParametricPlot`, etc, which own a option `PlotStyle`.

For instance,

```
ParametricPlot[{Sin[u], Sin[2 u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

which gives a normal graphic.

Now, I will give a value for the option `PlotStyle`, like `PlotStyle -> ps`.Namely, there are two cases as below:

- If the `ps` is a valid value, *Mathematica* will gives a normal result.
- If the  the value of`ps` is invald, *Mathematica* gives the following warning information

  > Graphics::gprim: Re was encountered where a Graphics primitive or directive was expected

However, if the `Plot` or `ParametricPlot` was used in user-defined function, I would like to **check the validity** of the value of option `PlotStyle`

Here is a small case

```
Options[ClosedBSpline] = {SplineStyle -> Blue};

ClosedBSpline[pts_, deg_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Module[{ss, points, knots, a, b},
  ss = OptionValue[SplineStyle];

  (*check the validity of SplineStyle*)
  (*if the value is invalid ,gives the warning 
    information and Return[$Failed]*)

  points = Join[pts, pts[[1 ;; deg]]];
  knots = Range[0, Length@points + deg];
  a = knots[[deg + 1]];
  b = knots[[-(deg + 1)]];
  ParametricPlot[
   CoxDeBoor[points, {deg, knots}, u], {u, a, b}, 
   PlotStyle -> ss, 
   Axes -> False]
 ]
```

Auxiliary function

```
searchSpan[knots_, u0_] :=
 With[{max = Max[knots]},
  If[u0 == max,
   Position[knots, max][[1, 1]] - 2,
   Ordering[UnitStep[u0 - knots], 1][[1]] - 2]
]

CoxDeBoor[pts_, {deg_, knots_}, u0_?NumericQ] :=
 Module[
    {i = searchSpan[knots, u0], coeff},
    coeff =
         Piecewise[
             {{(u0 - knots[[#1 + #2 + 1]])/(knots[[#1 + deg + 2]] -
                      knots[[#1 + #2 + 1]]),                  
              knots[[#1 + deg + 2]] != knots[[#1 + #2 + 1]]}}] &;
    First@
         Fold[
            MapThread[Dot, {#2, Partition[#1, 2, 1]}] &,
            pts[[i - deg + 1 ;; i + 1]],
            Table[
               {1 - coeff[j, k], coeff[j, k]},
               {k, 1, deg}, {j, i - deg, i - k}]] 
  ]
```

TEST

```
pts = {{-2, 2}, {0, 1}, {-2, 0}, {0, -1}, {-2, -2}, {-4, -4}, {2, -4}, 
       {4, 0}, {2, 4}, {-4, 4}};
ClosedBSpline[
 pts, 3, SplineStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Dashed, Blue]]
```

[image]

```
ClosedBSpline[pts, 3, SplineStyle -> 1]
ClosedBSpline[pts, 3, 
  SplineStyle -> Directive[Opacity[0.5], Dashe, Blue]]
```

[image]]

#### QUESTION

- How to check the validity of `SplineStyle`.Namely, I don't know all the **possible valid values** for the option `PlotStyle`?

Comment: Clearly `Graphics` is capable of making that determination, so an inelegant but possibly effective way to check your option values might be to feed the options you collected to a dummy `Graphics` and catch any ensuing errors...

Comment: @MarcoB THX, Could you give me a simple demo that applied your method?

Comment: Shutao, can you show a specific example of code that contains an "invalid" directive, and that gives you the error you mentioned in the question? In my experience, invalid directives in `SplineStyle` get silently ignored and no errors are generated.

Comment: @MarcoB , For instance, `ClosedBSpline[pts, 3, SplineStyle -> Directive[Opacit[0.5], Blue]]` or `ClosedBSpline[pts, 3, SplineStyle -> 1]` will give the warning information:) Please see my update.

Comment: What version of MMA do you run? I am on MMA 10.2 on Win7-64, and your problem examples simply *ignore the incorrect directives*, without returning an error. See [this result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4toMk.png). Do you have any special warnings enabled? What does the text of the errors say exactly?

Comment: @MarcoB My mma version is V9, please see [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bv7NB.png)

Answer (score 2):

Check `Menu/Help/DocumentationCenter/PlotStyle/Details`. There you will find this table:

[image]

listing all acceptable instances.

Have fun!

Comment: Alexei, I'm worried though that the list you refer to might not be complete. You will notice that it says "the directives [...] INCLUDE:". I take it to mean that those are a sample of the most common acceptable ones. It is pretty comprehensive though.

Comment: @MarcoB You may be right. May be not though, that is, it may be such an precise expression causing our misunderstanding. A proof would be, if somebody finds a counterexample. I guess, however, that this list might be enough to answer the OP question.

Comment: `Menu/Help/DocumetationCenter/Details` does not lead to any useful documentation article. Something important missing before `Details`?

Comment: @m_goldberg  Not that I know.

Comment: That list isn't complete. At a quick glance it's missing `AbsoluteDashing`, `LABColor`, `Thick`, `Dotted`, and friends. (`ref/Graphics` has the more complete table.)

Comment: @ Brett Champion Good to know. Why do not you write it as a regular answer? I find it is of value.

Answer (score 2):

In comments I had proposed the somewhat hackish idea to use a fake call to your actual plotting function itself (i.e. `ParametricPlot` in your case) to check the `PlotStyle` expression before using it to generate your actual plot.

I have since realized that unfortunately (or fortunately, depending on the points of view :-) I could not reproduce the behavior you see on version 9 in my installation of MMA v. 10.2, nor do I have have access to a v. 9 installation to play with.

Nevertheless, since there have been no further developments on your question, I decided to cobble together my idea and provide it as is, untested, for what it is worth. It seems to work fine to catch errors in other functions, but I'd appreciate it if you could test it in your case.

I would envision this code block being inserted within your `ClosedBSpline` module. Of course you will want to provide more appropriate code to handle the incorrect `PlotStyle`: for instance, on error you could reset `ss` to a valid default, etc.

```
Block[
 {x, y},
 Quiet@Check[
   (*fake plot, only here to see if an error is generated*)
   (*plot output is suppressed*)
   ParametricPlot[1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
     Frame -> None, Axes -> None, PlotStyle -> ss];,

   (*Code here that handles the incorrect plotstyle situation*)
   Print["The plot style definition is incorrect"],

   (*The error(s) to catch*)
   Graphics::gprim
   ]
]
```

Currently this will only react to the `Graphics::gprim` message, but you can provide a list of multiple messages to track, or alternatively remove the specification altogether, and it will react to any messages being generated.

`Quiet` suppresses the printing of the message. I have also prevented the generation of axes and frame in the plot to reduce the amount of wasted work, in hopes to keep the overhead minimal.

Comment: Dear MarcoB, I executed the code you given in MMA 9, however, there is no any warning information.

Comment: @Shutao Thank you for selecting my answer for your bounty! I am sorry to hear that the method I outlined doesn't seem to solve your problem. I hope that somebody else with access to MMA v.9 will weigh in on this as well.

Comment: Becacuse @MarcoB I think you have given me some hints and possible useful method:-)